# Error while installing Aruco using pip "pip install aruco".ERROR: Failed building wheel for aruco

Tags: python, aruco

Error while installing Aruco using pip "pip install aruco".
I'm trying to install the Aruco library but each time I'm getting the same error.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aruco

ERROR: Failed building wheel for aruco
Running setup.py clean for aruco
Failed to build aruco
Installing collected packages: aruco
Running setup.py install for aruco ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Then
Try this:

```
pip3 install aruco
```