# 'aruco' submodule for opencv-contrib-python not found

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, pip, aruco

I'm trying to use opencv's aruco library for a project and when I donwload opencv-contrib-python using 'pip install opencv-contrib-python' the aruco submodule doesn't show up.

I've made sure that 'opencv-python' is not installed (because I know that's a common problem) but otherwise I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Python version = 3.9
opencv-contrib-version = 4.6.0.66

```
Package               Version
--------------------- --------
numpy                 1.23.2
opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66
pip                   22.2.2
setuptools            65.3.0
wheel                 0.37.1
```

I have two pythons installed 3.9 and 3.10

Comment: `pip list`, [edit] and add to your question. -- using any virtual environments? multiple pythons? ...

Comment: Then use this sudo apt install opencv-python3. Worked for me today. Never used pip3.

Comment: I'm running on windows sadly 

Comment: `py -3.9 -m pip list` and `py -3.10 -m pip list`

Comment: I actually uninstalled python 3.10, so the only python now is 3.9

Comment: what IDE? or can I assume that there's no IDE involved that could mess things up, because you're running this by yourself from a console window?

Comment: I'm using visual studio code! Could that have an impact on the problem?

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235814/18359438) can work on my vscode.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python 
pip install aruco
```